# AngularJS one-way binding on custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I am using AngularJS highcharts (https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng)

I have this config and I need make sure it is only binded once. I looked up one-way binding on AngularJS and it says I need to use `::` if I am using AngularJs 1.3(Which I am ). But I am not sure how to use it on a custom directive.

```
 <highchart config="configtemp"></highchart>
```

I tried something like but it doesn't work

```
 <highchart config=":: configtemp"></highchart>
```

Comment: Could you further explain what exactly "it doesn't work" means. As per my comment below, using `::` will indeed prevent the value of the attribute `config` from changing, so if the highchart directive is gathering new config data, it's not from this scope value.

Answer (score 2):

In this regard custom directives work the same as angular directives. AngularJS highcharts has an isolate scope as per:

```
scope: {
    config: '=',
    disableDataWatch: '='
  },
```

So it's scope will consist of the values assigned to those attributes in the html. Thus

```
<highchart config=":: configtemp"></highchart>
```

will mean that on the directive scope `scope.config` will be equal to `::configtemp`. Since you have the `'::'` the value of `configtemp` will not change (better known as one-time binding) from it's first value as you suggested/expected. ([Example of this in plunker form](https://plnkr.co/edit/VevUDiaWD7IgLFXeAoc0?p=preview)).

Highcharts does have some extra logic, but ultimately it's internal config [is derived from this attribute/scope value](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/blob/master/src/highcharts-ng.js#L382).

Without further information, I cannot advise what "doesn't work".

Comment: I would like to use one config for multiple charts, would  it work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/u40vs8hk/ - yes, though the chart data comes from the `series` property on the config, so if you can't set this dynamically (due to one time binding) you'd end up with the same chart twice. Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm ending up with the same chart.. i dont think it would work but thanks for help tho